# Get Day of Week in Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to create a CQWP of a Calendar List and trying to show the "Day of the Week" like "Monday", Tuesday, ect. from the "EventDate" (which is the Start Date).  I'm having trouble with the xslt to display this.  Does anyone have examples?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be far easier to just create another column in the list. Let it be a calculated column with the formula

```
TEXT([DateField],"dddd")
```

for "Tuesday"

or

```
TEXT([DateField],"ddd")
```

for "Tue"